# What is gs-loc.apple.com?

Tags: macos, gps

I have little snitch installed and every time I resume my macbook pro gs-loc.apple.com on port 443 wants to connect. I'm thinking it's to find your location so that iCloud can display it. the exec is called locationd. I pretty sure that my guess is right. I just wanted to see what the community thought.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, it’s Location Services. The location is updated on a regular interval, or when an app requests it.

I worked it out while using Little Snitch, just like you. As there was a `loc` in the domain name, I figured it would be Location Services.

To confirm, I turned off Location Services, and sure enough, `locationd` shut down and no connections to `gs-loc` were made. To confirm again, I blocked `gs-loc`, and Location Services stopped working.

From: [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2141988?start=0&tstart=0)

> Locationd is a daemon that provides location services for OS X's "Core Location". This uses skyhook technology to figure out your mac's location (using WiFi). It's the same system used by the iPod Touch, and is also used by the iPhone (The iPhone also uses cell tower triangulation and GPS)